# Objective-C Proper way to create class with only one instance

Tags: objective-c, initialization

I am trying to implement a class, that subclasses `NSObject` directly, that can only have one instance available throughout the entire time the application using it is running.

Currently I have this approach:

```
// MyClass.h

@interface MyClass : NSObject

+(MyClass *) instance;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
// MyClass.m

// static instance of MyClass
static MyClass *s_instance;

@implementation MyClass

-(id) init
{
    [self dealloc];
    [NSException raise:@"No instances allowed of type MyClass" format:@"Cannot create instance of MyClass. Use the static instance method instead."];

    return nil;
}

-(id) initInstance
{
    return [super init];
}

+(MyClass *) instance {
    if (s_instance == nil)
    {
        s_instance = [[DefaultLiteralComparator alloc] initInstance];
    }

    return s_instance;    
}

@end
```

Is this the proper way to accomplish such a task?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do a little more than that.  This describes how an objective-c singleton should be implemented: [Objective-C Singleton](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/)

Comment: Thank you, I will use this solution!

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like

Comment: @ennuikiller The link is broken. have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, there is still a way to create a second instance of your class:

```
MyClass *secondInstance = [[MyClass alloc] initInstance]; //we have another instance!
```

What you want is to override your class's `+(id)alloc` method:

```
+(id)alloc{
    @synchronized(self){
        NSAssert(s_instance == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of singleton(MyClass)");
        s_instance = [super alloc];
        return s_instance;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the `initInstance` method is not in the header, only in the implementation...

Comment: You'll get a compiler warning, but that's it. It will still run, and create a second instance. Also, nothing prohibits a method of a class from creating another instance of itself.

Comment: Actually, you won't get a compiler warning, because the definition of initInstance comes before its only use.