# Singleton classes in Objective-C vs C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'm used to Objective-C and so I know that to create a singleton method all I do is this:

```
+ (void)myMethod
```

and to call it I type

```
#import MyClass;
[MyClass myMethod];
```

How do I do the same thing in C#?

Comment: That's not a singleton in objective-c, that's a class method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a singleton in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155688/what-is-a-singleton-in-c)

Comment: The `+` indicates that it's a class method (vs an instance method).

Comment: the + is a class method.  Here's one way to do an objective-c singleton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381085/how-to-create-singleton-class-in-objective-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods

Comment: (A class method is essentially the same as a "static method", though the Objective-C purists will scream that there's no resemblance.)

Comment: a singleton has a class or static method which always returns the same instance of the object - usually with some synchronization for thread safety.

Comment: Ok I see the answer I need below then. Thanks all.

Comment: As Hot Licks pointed out a static C# function is *similar* to a class method.  As for the C# singleton, see the possible duplicate I linked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the closest thing to your code in C#  (it is not exactly the same, because in Objective-C you can "override" static methods, but in C# you cannot).

```
class MyClass {
    static public void MyMethod() {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        MyClass.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: @dtb Now it should compile (I added an empty body to the method).

Comment: @bryanmac I know, but the OP asked to translate Objective C to C#, that's what I did.

Comment: OK - I didn't down vote - I simply clarified ... I realized you answered the exact question :\

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand from this debate what you really need. Here is the singleton pattern in C#:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static MyClass instance;

    private MyClass()
    {
    }

    public static GetInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new MyClass();
        return instance;
    }
}
```