# How to create an adWhirl Singleton to use 1 add banner across all view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, adwhirl

I've been reading all evening and it seems that to get an adWhirl ad use the same add banner across all view controllers, I need to create a singleton awView and use this in the ViewWillLoad & ViewWillUnload of each View.

I am having trouble getting this to work. I've found tons of AdWhirl tutorials but none that create a singleton.

I currently have this adWhirlSingleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AdWhirlDelegateProtocol.h"
#import "AdWhirlView.h"

@interface adWhirlSingleton : NSObject <AdWhirlDelegate> {
    AdWhirlView *awView;
    UIViewController *primaryView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) AdWhirlView *awView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *primaryView;

@end
```

adWhirlSingleton.m

```
#import "adWhirlSingleton.h"

@implementation adWhirlSingleton
@synthesize primaryView, awView;

-(NSString *)adWhirlApplicationKey
{
    return @"my key here";
}

-(UIViewController *)viewControllerForPresentingModalView
{
    return primaryView;
}

@end
```

I import adWhirlSingleton into my views, but when I type adWhirlSingleton.primaryView = self I doesn't recognize the primaryView.

What am I missing to implement this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singletons have a factory init method (the method will start with a `+` instead of a `-`) to ensure that only one gets created. You may have other things going on, but any object that doesn't make itself a singleton won't be a singleton.

Here is a [stack overflow question about creating singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381085/how-to-create-singleton-class-in-objective-c) that might help. This [one will also give examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like) There is also an excellent [Matt Gallagher post about them](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html). Once you create the singleton instance you will always reference it with something like
    [[adWhirlSingleton sharedSingleton] primaryView]
If you've just been starting out, the Application Delegate is a singleton, so if you see demo code that uses the Application Delegate and its shared instance, you will have some examples for how to reference a singleton.

Comment: Thanks Walter. That was some good links that explained a lot about Singletons. Got it working now :-)