# singleton class for webservices in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, web-services, xcode6

I'm new to iOS while I'm developing I am calling web services every where...I want like one single class for get,post,put methods...then call [self post];
    [parameters:....]... that means I want to call single methods for all get services and post.. please help me...how it is..

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        height, @"user[height]",
                        weight, @"user[weight]",
                        nil];
[httpClient postPath:@"/myobject" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

For AFNetworking 2.0 (and also using the new NSDictionary syntax):

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"user[height]": height,
                         @"user[weight]": weight};
[manager POST:@"https://example.com/myobject" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

From here you can create singleton class - [How to create singleton class in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381085/how-to-create-singleton-class-in-objective-c)

Then you need to create your own method with completion handler and call where you want.

Example: Post Method:

```
+(void)postWebserviceWithURL:(NSString*)webServiceURL withParam:(NSDictionary*)urlParameters withCompletion:(void(^)(NSDictionary*response))completion {
//Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the related answer.You should create nsobject classes something like webservices and create the singleton instance object like this.

```
+(WebServices *)sharedInstance{

    /* Use this to make it a singleton class */
    if (sharedObj==Nil) {
        sharedObj=[[WebServices alloc]init];
    }
    return sharedObj;
     /**/
}
```

using this singleton instance you can call the methods what ever you required.

```
Eg: [[webservices sharedInstance] post];
```

With in the method you can use the required web services hits such as post,get and put.

use the Nsnotifiers to consume the responses from the API hits.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
static CustomClass *sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

//Override your constructor for custom initialization if you want
    sharedInstance = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
});

return sharedInstance;
}
```

Then define your methods for CRUD actions.

simply access like

```
[[CustomClass sharedInstance] POST:...];
[[CustomClass sharedInstance] GET:...];
```